# only show events who are greater than or equal laravel

Tags: laravel, date

Im working in a project where I display different events in my view. The goal for now is to only show events that are upcoming, so it doesn't show events that are older than today.

The users of my page can create an event and set a sertain date for it.

The data is stored into my db like this:

```
$table->string('datum');
```

In the view it return it like this:

06.03.2019

My controller to return the data looks like this:

```
$date = date('d.m.Y');
$evententries = Event::where('datum', '>=', $date)->orderBy('datum', 'asc')->take(3)->get();
```

but it's somehow not working..

Anyone got any Ideas of how to fix this and what my issue is here?

btw, I'm using laravel 5.7.

Thank you :)

Comment: what do you get if you dd($evententries) beneath the variable in your controller?

Comment: i got an array with 3 items, like i want but only the 3 newest and if one of them has a date (2 months ago) it shows me this too

Comment: Collection {#279 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Event {#281 ▶}
    1 => Event {#282 ▶}
    2 => Event {#283 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: it looks like you are trying to compare a string to a date - in which case it won't work - it'd probably be best to have your migration save the column as date format using $table->date('datum');

Comment: i did it but it doesnt work either

Comment: yeah this is strange - because if you can an if statement comparing date to datum the condition is working correctly, i just can;t workout why your query isn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189661/discussion-between-codeboycode-and-monamuhr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm you are doing it on wrong way from begin...

First: why you are using string to store date value? there is much better options to store date within database...

Second: you are using date format which cannot be compared on that way (using < > =)

when you are comparing strings ie 08.03.2019 will be always smaller than 10.01.2016 because 1 > 0... so if you are comparing dates use:

1. db format for storing dates
2. for comparing use format yyyy-mm-dd because on that way even simple string comparison will give you correct result...

Comment: if i do it like this: 

$table->date('datum');

and then in my controller this:

$date = date('dd.mm.yyyy');

$evententries = Event::where('datum', '>=', $date)->orderBy('datum', 'asc')->take(3)->get();

Comment: date is always yyyy-mm-dd because that format is best for DB operations... later you display date on way you want in select